# Preventing mf.manifest.json Data Duplication in Angular 14 with Module Federation

Tags: micro-frontend, manifest.json, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm working on a project using Angular 14 with Module Federation to implement microfrontends. We've developed several microfrontends, but we're encountering a recurring issue: sometimes, when generating the mf.manifest.json file, certain data gets duplicated.

We've considered maintaining version control using an Excel file, but we believe there might be a more elegant solution. Is it possible to store these parameters in a database and, upon microfrontend execution, automatically update the mf.manifest.json file to be generated without duplicates?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or experiences that can be shared to efficiently address this issue. Thank you!

I attempted to address the duplication issue by manually inspecting the data sources used to generate the mf.manifest.json file. Additionally, I explored the possibility of implementing a custom script to post-process the manifest file and remove any duplicate entries. However, these approaches proved to be labor-intensive and prone to errors, especially as the number of microfrontends increased.